# When $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{n}^{n+1}f(x)dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Is the following always true? (i.e. if both converges, limits are equal; if one diverges, the other must diverge; EXCLUDE the case where the limit keeps "jumping")

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)\;dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{n}^{n+1}f(x)\;dx
$$

When $f(x)$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$, how to argue that the above equality holds?

Comment: What sort of integral is this? An improper Riemann integral?

Comment: Consider any finite summation; $$ \sum_{n=0}^N \int_n^{n+1} f(x)\,dx = \int_0^N f(x)\,dx. $$
Isn't your question then reduced to one of the nature of improper integration and the limit of large integers versus large reals?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Yes, an improper Riemann integral.

Comment: @Jason Does the equality for finite summation always hold?

Answer (score 1):

In fact they are not the same. But it is just nitpicking on definition of integral.

Take for example $f(x) = \sin(2\pi x)$. Than
$$
F(x) = \int_0^x \sin(2\pi t) dt = \frac{-1}{2 \pi}\cos(2\pi x)
$$
and limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} F(x)$ does not exists.

On other hand
$$
\int^{n+1}_n \sin(2\pi t) dt = 0 
$$
for every $n$.

So the sum on right side exists but the integral on left does not.

Comment: Yes, the equality does not hold when limit keeps "jumping". But what I mean is excluding this case, only consider the cases where the limit is either a real number or $\pm\infty$

Comment: Sorry I missed that bit in question.

Comment: The bit was added after you posted this answer.